# Pushing a list with PushBullet API returns error 400

Tags: json, api, http, bad-request, pushbullet

I'm trying to send a new list with the PushBullet API using an http request. I use following json data to send to push:
`{
    "items":[
        {
            "checked":false,
            "text":"a"
        },{
            "checked":true,
            "text":"b"
        },{
            "checked":false,
            "text":"c"
        }
    ],
    "title":"a",
    "type":"list"
}`

The content type is set to "application/json" and I use the same syntax for the list as the server returns when requesting my push history. Still I get error 400 (bad request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since lists have been deprecated, you can still use them, but they do not appear in the most recent docs.  You can find them in older versions of the docs though: https://docs.pushbullet.com/v3/#pushes

Items needs to be a list of strings, not a list of objects.  Part of the weirdness that is lists.

Also official pushbullet clients no longer support lists to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. Does this mean that adresses are also depricated?